# PHP echo out jQuery in IF statement

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

EDIT: What a TW*T. Sorry everyone for wasting your time. Just missed a Google jQuery link on one F'in page. Whoops.

Hi, i have a div containing 3 forms. These should be the only thing on the screen on page load. When any of them are submitted, a graph gets shown below. What i'm trying to do is within the PHP IF statement is make the div disappear that contains the forms. Sound simple?

This is my code:

```
if($_GET['submit1']){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#options').css('display','none');</script>";
```

However, when i do submit one of the forms (therefore a $_GET has occurred) the div is still there??

EDIT:

If i try people answer on one line i get this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'
```

But if i put in people's multiline answers, no error, but div still shows!

Comment: Can you edit the answer with the parse error you're receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to hide the forms with JavaScript?

Simply do it with PHP:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['submit1'])) {
?>
        //<form> your form HTML here
<?php
    } else {        
?>
        <p>Your submitted data: <?php print_r($_GET); ?></p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

So your forms are only shown if you have NOT submitted one of them. You might have to adjust the parameters if you have multiple forms, for example

```
if(!isset($_GET['submit1']) && !isset($_GET['submit2'])) {
```

**Edit**: If you want to keep your forms after submitting but only hide it, you could do it that way:

```
<?php
    $formsVisible  = !isset($_GET['submit1']));
    $formsDisplay  = $formsVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
?>
<form style="display:<?php echo $formsDisplay; ?>">
<!-- ... --->
</form>
```

Comment: The reason i did it with javascript is so i could add a button to slideToggle() the form back in/out with jQuery

Comment: Looks good, i'm just a little confused. I have forms, then on same page, but below the form, the PHP if $_GET. So i'm not sure how to fit your answer in

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a DOM ready event:

```
if($_GET['submit1']) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
    echo '    $(function() {'              . "\n";
    echo '        $("#options").hide();'   . "\n";
    echo '    });'                         . "\n";
    echo '</script>'                       . "\n";
}
```

Comment: echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){$('#options').hide();});</script>"; produces an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Comment: Copy and paste my example verbatim.

Comment: In your pasted example, you did not include the terminating bracket for the if block.  `}`.  Maybe you are adding it with my example, but it occurs later in your script, and that is what is breaking.

Comment: Hi Stephen, i have copied & pasted correctly, i get no error, but the div still shows!?

Comment: Question:  If you hardcode the script (outside the if block) so that it is supposed to hide the div *every time*, does it work?

Comment: Then your problem is not with PHP.  It looks like jquery is not loading properly.

Comment: What a TW*T. Sorry everyone for wasting your time. Just missed a Google jQuery link on one F'in page. Whoops

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
You are getting a parse error because you're using double quotes, so the php parser is reading the dollar sign as a php variable.  I would switch to a single quote php syntax to make your life easier:

```
if($_GET['submit1']){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ 
            $("#options").css("display","none");
        });
    </script>';
}
```

Be sure to wrap your jquery code in the onLoad function `$(function(){};`